# Error Code: 1048, SQL State: 23000 Column 'colegiado_id' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

Olá, este erro

```
"[Error Code: 1048, SQL State: 23000]  Column 'colegiado_id' cannot be null"
```

acontece quando eu tento rodar o comando SQL abaixo diretamente no MySQL:

```
start transaction;
INSERT INTO EspecialistasColegiados (colegiado_id, especialista_id) (
    select
        col.id as colegiado_id,
        esp.id as especialista_id

    from Especialista esp
        inner join importacao imp ON imp.idimportacao = esp.id
        left join Colegiado col ON col.nome like concat('%',imp.CURSOS,'%')
    );
rollback;
```

Answer (score 1):

A coluna "colegiado_id" não pode ser nula. Você tem duas alternativas:

realizar um alter table na tabela EspecialistasColegiados para aceitar valor nulo ou alterar a consulta (select) para não retornar valores nulos

Alter na tabela

```
ALTER TABLE `MyTable` ALTER COLUMN `MinhaColuna` INT DEFAULT NULL;
```

Modificar select

```
 start transaction;
 INSERT INTO EspecialistasColegiados (colegiado_id, especialista_id) (
select
    col.id as colegiado_id,
    esp.id as especialista_id

from Especialista esp
    inner join importacao imp ON imp.idimportacao = esp.id
    left join Colegiado col ON col.nome like concat('%',imp.CURSOS,'%')
where colegiado_id IS NOT NULL
 );
rollback;
```

Comment: Apenas uma observação, se alterar para não aceitar (conforme o select acima) NULL o dado não vai ser inserido.